Why does Angular 18 SSR seem like CSR in local tests?
I'm currently running an angular 18 SSR app in mi local machine; my app consumes a graphql api using apollo.
I haven't errors with the functionality but when i check in the browser, in the inspections tool in network (fetch), i see the api graphql consume and i understand when an app is SSR, that type of consume must not appear in network browser, the another problem is when in the browser i disable javascript, the app SSR functionality doesn't works; then my app angular SSR is working bad or i'm not having another concept in mind?.
Maybe because in my app i configure the access to the localstorage of the user with this?
BrowserStorageService.ts:
import { Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const BROWSER_STORAGE = new InjectionToken<Storage>('Browser Storage', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => localStorage,
});

@Injectable()
  export class BrowserStorageService {
  constructor(@Inject(BROWSER_STORAGE) public storage: Storage) {}

get(key: string) {
  return this.storage.getItem(key);
}

set(key: string, value: string) {
 this.storage.setItem(key, value);
}

remove(key: string) {
  this.storage.removeItem(key);
}

clear() {
 this.storage.clear();
}
}

app.config.server.ts:
import { mergeApplicationConfig, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { appConfig } from './app.config';
import { BrowserStorageService } from '@core/services/browser-storage.service';
import { BrowserStorageServerService } from '@core/services/browser-storage-server.service';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
   provideServerRendering(),
   {
    provide: BrowserStorageService,
    useClass: BrowserStorageServerService,
   }
  ]
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);

